# PHP Cli write text to file

Tags: php, fopen, fwrite

I am trying to run a CLI php script, while most of it works, I am not able to dump the log file.

## Code:

```
    private function WriteLogForCLI($msg){
        try{
            $ttw = " *************************************************** " . PHP_EOL;
            $ttw .= " *" . PHP_EOL;
            $ttw .= " * TIME STAMP: " . date("m/d/Y H:i:s");
            $ttw .= " *" . PHP_EOL;
            $ttw .= " * $msg" . PHP_EOL;
            $ttw .= " *" . PHP_EOL;
            $ttw .= " *************************************************** " . PHP_EOL;
            $logfile = str_replace('//', '/', FCPATH . 'assets/logs/' . date("m-d-Y") . '.txt');                
            $fh = fopen($logile, 'wb');                 
            //var_dump($fh);
            //var_dump($ttw);               
            fwrite($fh, $ttw); 
            fclose($fh);                
            //var_dump($logfile);
        }catch(Exception $e){
            var_dump($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

`$logfile` path is correct, and is the absolute location of where this file should be located... for instance /var/www/the_site/assets/logs/03-06-2014.txt is `var_dump`'d which is correct.

I have made sure the directory this is written to has 0777 access.

What can I do to make this work?  All I am trying to do is write a log file that has a `$msg`, but have it run from cli.

I've tried it with my normal login, and the root login and the file never gets written.

Server is Ubuntu 13.10 server, with PHP 5.5.3

Comment: change  $fh = fopen($logile, 'wb'); to  $fh = fopen($logfile, 'wb');

Comment: omfg... seriously!  LMAO  oh... what a day...  yep... wanna post that as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have

```
$logfile = str_replace('//', '/', FCPATH . 'assets/logs/' . date("m-d-Y") . '.txt');
```

but, you are using $logile in fopen function

```
$fh = fopen($logile, 'wb');
```

so, change to

```
$fh = fopen($logfile, 'wb');
```